# Looking for a working web video player

Tags: html, flash, video, streaming, video-streaming

After several years working with commercial and custom Flash video players, such as Flowplayer and jwplayer, I decided to open my work to html5. I like the idea of having a Flash impersonation of html5, so I tried medialements.js, video.js and jplayer. None of them are production ready and they all fail to meet my goal, which is playing a video on a webpage, desktop and mobile, live and vod.

Does anyone has a suggestion for a working web video player, apart from the commercial ones?

TIA

greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get to what you are saying. Videojs is a leader in HTML5 video and considered state of the art by many though I think it falls short on some aspects especially for iOS/Android and Live streaming. Here is a list that compares [some common actors of the market](http://praegnanz.de/html5video/).

After much time playing with the different players available I decided to build my own HTML5 video jQuery based player. I learned so much while doing so and if you are planning on re-using it for your projects *it will be much faster* to tweak your own player rather than trying to build something up on a player someone else built. Now doing so requires you like JavaScript and are happy to deal with the cross browser testing. This article can give you a place to [start](http://dev.opera.com/articles/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/). Digging in further would require you take on board the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html).

Live streaming in HTML5 video is limited today: HLS for iOS and Android > 4.1 and coming in fast MPEG DASH (it has a JS lib for live and on demand [here](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki)). If you want to cover a large audience for live video streaming you still need to consider flash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was having the same feeling, I would rather have written my own player from the start - or keep using Flowplayer despite its crazy license price. I was leaving Flash because of the iPad but I realize the iPad is not html5 ready and falls short when it has to deal with videos. iPad is really the new IE6 :( http://blog.millermedeiros.com/ipad-is-the-new-ie6/

Comment: Apple has not committed to Mr. Jobs announcement that it will embrace the open web. Many features of the new web are just absent from iOS as of today: WebRTC, video as a source for canvas, getUserMedia API, VP8 ... I believe they went on a crusade against flash because it was a business strategy to shake Adobe. It is a bit sad because the iPad is actually a great device on a user experience perspective ... it is just not as nice as it seems for developers.

Comment: Very true. After having grown to hate the iPad as a user, I'm learning to hate it as a developer. Unfortunatly it has been the same for many goodies from the Fruit.